# How can I connect to the same server in multiple irssi instances?

Tags: irssi

I have an irssi session which is connected to Freenode (via `/server fn`), in which I am in multiple related channels. This session is inside of a tmux instance which has other terminals, also related to this topic. I have set irssi to automatically authenticate me via NickServ.

Now I want to open a completely separate terminal and connect to Freenode via irssi again, so I can join an unrelated channel. However, when I open irssi and `/server fn` again, it fails to authenticate me as I am already connected to the server in the other irssi session.

I can connect to the same server with different authenticated accounts, but I want to have multiple irssi instances authenticated with the same account.

Is there any way I can be connected to the same server (but have different channels open) in two separate irssi instances?

Comment: My system has not the same problem with **freenode** with multiple terminals by irssi 0.8.17; I suggest to try create another user in system and try connect with different users.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar I am trying to connect to freenode with the same authenticated account in multiple terminals. Of course, I can connect to the same server with different accounts, but as I mentioned in the question that's not what I want to do. I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: I do not know the answer. There is a another ability to [have split window](https://quadpoint.org/articles/irssisplit/) using `/window` command.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar That does not answer my question. I am trying to connect to the same server with the same account in two separate terminals.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @darnir Exactly what the title states: Connect to Freenode simultaneously in more than one terminal window.

Comment: And why can't you simply connect back into your tmux session?

Comment: @darnir 1.) The tmux session also has other terminals, not just the irssi session. 2.) I want the irssi instances to be completely separate, so that, for example, I can join a channel in one of them and not see it in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because of how the IRC protocol works. Each client connection owns a unique IRC nickname; if you connect to the same IRC network a 2nd time, the new client must choose a different nickname from the first.

You might be able to approximate the behaviour you want using the `PROXY` module of irssi; see e.g. https://michael.lustfield.net/linux/irssi-as-a-proxy. I imagine you could have your irssi, with the proxy module loaded, connected to your IRC server, and then you could have separate sub-clients connecting to the proxying irssi. This way, you'd only have one client on the real IRC network, not several clients trying to use the same nickname. I haven't tried it, though.